# Are two spaces the same if their topologies are the same?

Tags: general-topology

For example, if we have $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology and $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ with the product topology, is it sufficient to say $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ by simply showing that their topologies are the same?

Comment: Each parallelepiped have sphere inside and reverse.

Comment: In topology, spaces are "the same" if there is a homeomorphism between them. For example $[0,2\pi) \simeq \mathbb{S}^1$, but I would not say that $[0,2\pi) = \mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: @Dayton you're missing a quotient somwewhere, no? Removing a point of $[0,2\pi)$ can make it disconnected, whereas removing a point of the unit circle doesn't affect its path connectedness. These aren't homeomorphic.

Comment: The word "same" needs to be made precise, otherwise the question is too vague because "the same" does not have any set meaning in mathematics. What does "the same" mean to you in the context of your post? Do you mean they are the same set? Do you mean they are the same set as well as the same topology on that set? Do you mean they are homeomorphic spaces?

Comment: @Dayton $\Bbb S^1$ is compact, $[0;2\pi)$ is not (assuming the usual topologies). Continuous maps preserve compactness so these two cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: @qualcuno  Yes sorry... How about $[0,1]$ and $[0, 1/2]$, that's a more trivial example. We have $[0,1]\simeq [0,1/2]$ in the sense of homeomorphsim, but not $[0,1] = [0,1/2]$

Comment: @Dayton sure, those will do.

Comment: I would point out that there is an implicit sense in which we do use $=$ instead of $\cong$ when talking about homeomorphic spaces. Even for $S^1$, we speak of _the_ circle, even though we could be using any realization or embedding of it. It's similar to how in algebra you might use $=$ instead for certain objects that are isomorphic, if there's an understanding that we really do mean these things are the same.

Comment: @LeeMosher I mean "will two sets be equal if their topologies are the same?"

Comment: Again, topologies being the same _usually_ means homeomorphic, and in the definition of a homeomorphism, you have a bijection on the underlying sets, so as sets they are necessarily equivalent.

Comment: @OsamaGhani: But then, for sets “equal” means “have the same elements”, which is a stronger statement than “are in bijection” (which just means they have the same cardinality).

Comment: Yeah I said equivalent (not equal) for that reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question lacks some precision, because "the same" does not have any set meaning in mathematics. What does "the same" mean to you?

Nonetheless, no matter *how* one interprets "the same" for this particular post, the answer is an unequivocal "Yes".

Let me explain that answer in the most plain, ordinary, but mathematically precise manner, in terms of set theory.

First we have an equation of sets $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$: each is the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \in \mathbb R$ and $y \in \mathbb R$.

Second, if we let $\mathcal T_m$ denote the standard metric topology on $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathcal T_p$ the product topology on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R = R^2$, then each is a subset of the power set $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^2)$, and again we have an equation of sets $\mathcal T_m = \mathcal T_p$. There is something to prove here, which is alluded to in the comment of @zkutch: one must prove that each open ball can be expressed as a union of rectangles; and each open rectangle can be expressed as a union of open balls; it follows, from the definition of the topologies $\mathcal T_m$ and $\mathcal T_p$, that they are equal.

Finally, a topological space is formally an ordered pair $(X,\mathcal T)$ where $\mathcal T$ is a topology on the set $X$. So $(\mathbb R^2,\mathcal T_m)$ is a topological space with the metric topology, and $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R,\mathcal T_p)$ is a topological space with the product topology, but the first entries of these ordered pairs are equal $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, and the second entries of these ordered pairs are equal $\mathcal T_m = \mathcal T_p$, so we have an equation of ordered pairs
$$(\mathbb R^2,\mathcal T_m) = (\mathbb R \times \mathbb R,\mathcal T_p)
$$

So yes, on all levels I can think of, these two topological spaces are *the same*.

---

To address your final comments, it is quite possible for one single set $X$ to have two different topologies $\mathcal T_1 \ne \mathcal T_2$, and therefore $X=X$ whereas $(X,\mathcal T_1) \ne (X,\mathcal T_2)$. For an example, on $\mathbb R^2$ take the standard metric topology $\mathcal T_1 = \mathcal T_m$ and the discrete topology $\mathcal T_2 = \mathcal P(\mathbb R^2)$.

Comment: this is a really detailed answer, thanks for that!